# broadcastreceiver does not kick in after rebooting

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-broadcastreceiver

Good day,

I am creating an app based on this.

[BroadcastReceiver and alarmManager Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429726/broadcastreceiver-and-alarmmanager-android)

it is running smoothly,
then I try to make it run even the client boot its phone by adding this.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

 <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

the problem is, broadcastreceiver is lost after reboot.

My **BroadcastReceiver** looks like this

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Don't panik but your time is up!!!!.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Vibrate the mobile phone
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2000);
    }
}
```

}

This is already fix. Thanks. (for future reference) :)

Comment: In your `BroadcastReceiver`, did you listen to `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` action? Please add your receiver class code.

Comment: hi, i posted my broadcastreceiver, do you mind looking it what could be the missing part? thanks!

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update to the following.

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            //Do your stuffs here
        }
    }
```