# Why isn't my Android notification triggering in the future, only the past?

Tags: android, date, datepicker, notifications, alarmmanager

I have searched around and am literally at my wits end with an issue with my Android notifications.

I am trying to implement a notification to trigger at a pre-defined time when the user selects a date from the `DatePicker` (*e.g. always at 08:00 on the date chosen*).

The notification works in as much as I can trigger it manually, so I know the code for it works.

I am populating my `Calendar` by grabbing the date from the `DatePicker` callback and can log it so that I know the date I'm using is correct, and I'm converting this to milliseconds to use for setting the alarm.

The notification will trigger immediately if I select a date or time in the past (*as per the default action of Android*), so it is recognising my date and time as valid to know that it is in the past.

**But, the problem is that it will not trigger if I set a time in the future and I simply cannot work out why.**

This is my `onDateSet()` method callback from the `DatePicker` where I am getting the Year, Month and Day, and then setting the `HOUR_OF_DAY` and `MINUTE` (*currently set to 13:15 for testing purposes*)...

```
//Add the chosen date to the DB (for the birthday)
//Callback implemented from DatePickerFragment Class
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    //Create a new string from the date
    String date = String.valueOf(new StringBuilder()
            .append(dayOfMonth)
            .append("-")
            .append(month + 1)
            .append("-")
            .append(year));

    updateDB_Birthday(date);
    dbHelper.updateIsOwned(beanieID, 1);

    //Convert date set to millis for use with notifying when set
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    long myTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    Log.v("z! Calendar", "" + calendar.getTime());

    //Create Notification to go off on the beanie's birthday
    notificationAlarmManager(myTime);
}
```

...this is my Notification Alarm Manager...

```
private void notificationAlarmManager(long myTime) {

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    notificationReceiver notificationReceiver = new notificationReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("ALARM_ACTION");
    registerReceiver(notificationReceiver, filter);

    Intent intent = new Intent("ALARM_ACTION");
    intent.putExtra("param", "My scheduled action");
    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myTime, operation);
}
```

...and this is my BroadcastReceiver class...

```
public class notificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(beanieImage)
                        .setContentTitle("Beanie Notification")
                        .setContentText("It's " + beanieName + "'s Birthday today!")
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

        //Add an intent
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ItemDetail.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("EXTRAS_ID", beanieID);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("EXTRAS_NAME", beanieName);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("EXTRAS_IMAGE", beanieImage);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("EXTRAS_BIRTHDAY", beanieBirthday);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("EXTRAS_IS_OWNED", isOwned);

        //Add pending intent
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //Launch activity on click of notification
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(001, builder.build());
    }
}
```

I've been stuck on this for a few days now and it's the last thing needed to finish this app, so any help will be MASSIVELY appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

**P.S.**
I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40051729/how-do-i-add-a-trigger-date-to-my-android-notification) regarding this yesterday, but apparently my question "*didn't show enough research effort*" even though it was my research that has gotten me this far. I have done plenty of 'homework' so please don't think I'm taking to this forum lightly, it's pretty much a last request.

Comment: `AlarmManager` request gets deleted on restarts. Can that be the cause here?

Comment: For my testing I have set it to be a couple of minutes in the future and have just sat and watched the specified time come and go, so I don't think so. Plus, I have read that this is what the BroadcastReciever is for.

Comment: @MikeM. My bad, I'll bear that in mind for next time, thanks.

Comment: Are you closing your app after setting the alarm? You're registering the Receiver dynamically, so if the `Context` it's on goes away, your alarm won't do anything. You should instead register the Receiver class in the manifest, and also use an explicit `Intent` for the broadcast. That is, an `Intent` that specifies the Receiver class. Also `AlarmManager#set()` is not exact since KitKat, if your `targetSdkVersion` >= 19, so keep that in mind when waiting on your alarm.

Comment: @MikeM. No, as I said I'm setting the alarm and going cross-eyed whilst staring at the screen waiting for the time to tick over. So setting the receiver as I've done isn't going to work? Is there any change you could please show me what I need for the Manifest, I've seen some people add a variety of things in different places, but nothing consistent.

Comment: @MikeM. ...and yes, when I read that the alarm is inExact my eyes lit up at the prospect of it just not going off at the exact time, but then I waited for a few more minutes each time and... nothing...

Comment: Registering in the manifest would simply be a `<receiver>` element with a `name` attribute pointing to your Receiver class, located within the `<application>` tags, like is shown in the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429726/broadcastreceiver-and-alarmmanager-android). However, if you're just setting it a bit ahead and waiting with the app open, then that wouldn't be the first thing I'd think is wrong, especially if you have no problem getting it to fire immediately when set in the past. Everything else looks OK, though.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for that, but I read through the post and comments (and the tutorial they've followed) and implemented the registration through the manifest, but sadly to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

So some how, i was able to find why it didn't work.
Here is the answer. It works for me.
In the AndroidManifest.xml, add following receiver to application element.

```
<receiver android:name=".notificationReceiver"
     android:enabled="true">
     <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Or just register like this

```
    <receiver 
        android:name=".notificationReceiver"
    </receiver>
```